# Adding system time and date to pdf with ggsave

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2

I have a pdf file that I trying to print with the time and date on the name of the pdf file. I tried using alot of different ways but still nothing. 
Can you please help me with that? 
The code for printing to pdf is below:

```
ggsave("Title of file.pdf", marrangeGrob(grobs = plots_list, nrow=1, ncol=1))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
ggsave(paste0("Title_of_file_"
              , format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M")
              , ".pdf")
       , marrangeGrob(grobs = plots_list, nrow=1, ncol=1))
```

see help for `strptime` for more information on formatting options.

Comment: Thank you. It puts a file on the computer but its not pdf and its 0 KB in size

Comment: Does it work when you just use "title_of_file.pdf"? My initial thought is that the error is caused by `marrangeGrob`. It worked for me using a regular ggplot object in place of your call, but without `plots_list` I cannot test your use case

Comment: The colon might be causing the problem. Try replacing it with a dash